# The commit transaction has no corresponding begin transaction?

Tags: sql-server, transactions, commit, rollback

I am trying to check to see the number of persons in a parish and issue a rollback command if the number of customers in the parish has gone over 5. This is what I was trying but getting the error when executing the procedure.

```
Create Procedure RollBackTest
(
@Id                 integer,
@Name               varchar(20),
@Date_of_Birth      date,
@Gender             char(1),
@Parish             varchar(20),
@Mobile             integer,
@Mobile_Provider    varchar(7),
@age                integer,
@age_category       varchar(20),
@MaritalStatus      char(1)
)
As
Begin
Begin Transaction MarketingListInsert
    If ((Select Count (*) from marketing_list where Parish=@Parish)<5)
        Begin
            Insert Into marketing_list
            Values

(@Id,@Name,@Date_of_Birth,@Gender,@Parish,@Mobile,@Mobile_Provider,@age,@age_category,@MaritalStatus)
        End
    Else
        Begin
            RollBack Transaction MarketingListInsert
        End
Commit Transaction
End

Execute "RollBackTest" 1856969,'John   
Walker','09/10/1990','M','Manchester',8727399,'Claro',0,'','S';
```

Comment: Move `Commit transaction` after `INSERT VALUE..`. Anyway you should use BEGIN TRY/CATCH blocks for error handling

Comment: tried that and executed successfully but didnt insert anything. shouldnt I have gotten a rollback command because the parish is more than 5 @lad2025?

Comment: The problem is that if it gets to rollback nothing has happened - it hasnt inserted anything for you to need to rollback. You are using transactions incorrectly. As the other comment says look at BEGIN TRY/CATCH.

Comment: Also its worth pointing out a single insert statement will either entirely succeed or fail before it changes any data - it cant get part way through and fail and leave data part inserted - SQL server handles this for you. So a transaction is not neccessary in the above procedure. You would only need a transaction if you were performing multiple inserts / updates one after the other.